# Ошибка requests python proxy

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Есть код, который делает запрос к чекеру IP:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent

headers = {
    'User-Agent': fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
}

proxies = {
    'https': 'https://185.128.242.4:45629'
}

url = "https://ipinfo.io/json"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

При запуске выдаёт мои данные, а не прокси. Иногда выводит ошибку

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipinfo.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /json (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001EFE66B70D0>, 'Connection to 103.167.172.104 timed out. (connect timeout=None)')))
```

(это, я как понимаю, прокси не рабочий попадается). Пробовал перебирать множество прокси, но не помогает. Помогите, плиз

Comment: P. S. использовал некоторые прокси отсюда: https://github.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List/blob/master/http.txt